# Htaccess to Nginx redirection

Tags: nginx, redirection

I have this redirection on htaccess

`RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^add_item?$ produits.php [NC,L]`

Now i use nginx, how to transfer it?

Comment: redirect or rewrite? the difference is important - your apache is doing a rewrite, but you want a redirect

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not do what you expect?

Comment: There is a folder in the app called api
in that folder there is a .htaccess file that has this function, API is not working in Nginx
This is the folder parth in my app : backs48823/api

Answer (score 1):

You can see similar rules converted to nginx.conf below.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_domain.com;

    location /add_item {
        rewrite ^/add_item?$ /produits.php last;
    }

    # You can add other rules...
}
```

Comment: There is a folder in the app called api
in that folder there is a .htaccess file that has this function, API is not working in Nginx
This is the folder parth in my app : backs48823/api

Comment: Okay, you can use de below config..

`
    location /backs48823/api {

        location /backs48823/api/add_item {
            rewrite ^/backs48823/api/add_item?$ /backs48823/api/produits.php last;
        }

        # Other configs...
    }
`

Comment: When I add this code, I get : 405 Not Allowed

Answer (score 1):

No, nginx does not support .htaccess files. The .htaccess file is a configuration file used by the Apache web server to control the behavior of a specific directory or part of a website. Nginx, on the other hand, uses a different approach to configuration, typically utilizing a central configuration file (nginx.conf) and, if needed, including separate configuration files for individual sites or components.

Add these lines in your nginx configuration for redirection.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_domain.com;

    location /add_item {
        rewrite ^/add_item?$ /produits.php last;
    }

    # You can add other rules...
}
```

Comment: There is a folder in the app called api
in that folder there is a .htaccess file that has this function, API is not working in Nginx
This is the folder parth in my app : backs48823/api